# Thread Pool Issue

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, threadpool

Situation:

I have a thread pool of 64 threads. I have a shared buffer, in which I put and get "works" in a synchronous and organized way. As a normal thread pool should work. It all works fine.

Problem:

Inside main(), I want to put a work in the shared buffer and I want a thread in the thread pool to execute it. However, I need main() to wait before that thread finishes that work. Normally I would pthread_join() it, but i don't know which thread is running the work.

Sorry if I didn't make myself very clear, but I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Include a synchro object,(eg. semaphore), in the work struct. Issue the work and wait on the synchro.  Have the pool threads signal the synchro when they have finished.  Don't go near join() unless at gunpoint.